# Blackberry App Descriptor error

Tags: xml, blackberry, java-7, blackberry-eclipse-plugin

Here is my Full descriptor file for blackberry application It has jre7.0 running with eclipse BB Plugin .

```
<Properties ModelVersion="1.1.2">

  <General Title="appname" Version="1.1" Vendor="companyname" Description="Developed by Companyname"/>

  <Application Type="BlackBerry Application" MainMIDletName="" MainArgs="" HomeScreenPosition="0" StartupTier="7" IsSystemModule="false" IsAutostartup="false"/>

  <Resources hasTitleResource="false" TitleResourceBundleName="" TitleResourceBundleRelativePath="" TitleResourceBundleClassName="" TitleResourceBundleKey="" DescriptionId="">

    <Icons>

      <Icon CanonicalFileName="res/images/50x50.png" IsFocus="false"/>

    </Icons>

  </Resources>

  <KeywordResources KeywordResourceBundleName="" KeywordResourceBundleRelativePath="" KeywordResourceBundleClassName="" KeywordResourceBundleKey=""/>

  <Compile OutputCompilerMessages="false" ConvertImages="false" CreateWarningForNoExportedRoutine="true" CompressResources="false" AliasList="">

    <PreprocessorDefines/>

  </Compile>

  <Packaging PreBuildStep="" PostBuildStep="" CleanStep="" OutputFileName="appname" OutputFolder="deliverables" GenerateALXFile="true">

    <AlxFiles/>

  </Packaging>

  <HiddenProperties>

    <ClassProtection/>

    <PackageProtection/>

  </HiddenProperties>

  <AlternateEntryPoints/>

</Properties>
```

I am getting error as seen below in Blackberry build descriptor file

for line

```
<KeywordResources KeywordResourceBundleName="" KeywordResourceBundleRelativePath="" KeywordResourceBundleClassName="" KeywordResourceBundleKey=""/>
```

Error as seen below

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
cvc-complex-type.2.4.a: Invalid content was found starting with element 'KeywordResources'. One of '{Compile}' is expected. BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml   line 11 XML Problem
```

Comment: Can you please provide your complete BlackBerry_App_Descriptor.xml file.

Comment: I deleted this line and now it works dunno the reason but

Comment: Thanks for letting us know _ I suggest you put this in as an answer and mark it appropriately to make it easier for the next person to find.  If I was guessing, I would suspect there was some non display character in there mucking things up.  Just a guess...